# 7 day chat suspension

Tags: support, chat

Why have I received a 7 day chat suspension? I do not recall doing anything harmful or bad for the chatroom, except maybe posting faces, but I don't see how that warrants a 7 day ban.

## EDIT

### I don't make the best decisions late at night.

Comment: Chat suspensions become longer and longer the more you get, and I believe the length is caused by that.

Comment: @NathanMerrill what is the limit?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it might have [something to do with this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34675046#34675046)

Comment: I seem to recall one of the mods mentioning on another meta thread that the limit is 9999 days, but I wouldn't advise trying to verify it empirically.

Comment: @PeterTaylor i think it was actually 9999 hours

Comment: Regarding chat suspension limits, it's high. Very high. ([Dennis says 9999 hours here.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11139/lets-talk-about-chat-again#comment36551_11139)) Regarding your quote, strikeout formatting is typically used to depict saying one thing, then back-tracking and saying something else. I'm not sure you can honestly claim that you didn't intend to call mods Nazis. Besides that, you *also* essentially implied that Germans in the 1940s were Nazis, which is very offensive.

Comment: @wat: Which is *still* a very broad brush, and still offensive.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted so much? Is it off topic?

Comment: @Anush the situation that happened here was due to me being, at the time, a dumb 15 year old and not thinking about the real meaning of what I was saying

Answer (score 17):

#### Regarding that message

- You must have no idea what the Nazis were/are or what they have done if you think calling someone a Nazi for deleting chat messages or handing out 30-minute suspensions is even remotely acceptable.

  Other parts of the internet may tolerate these insults, but this is not one of those parts. Stack Exchange's prime directive is to [Be Nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and there's nothing nice about comparing us moderators with genocidal mass murderers.
- You didn't just say *Nazis*, you used the euphemism *crazy 1940s germans*. That makes it *worse*. Much worse. As usual with dictatorships, many/most Germans didn't actually agree with what the government was doing and definitely weren't Nazis. Saying otherwise falls somewhere between stereotypes and hate speech.
- Just because you strikethrough parts of your message doesn't mean you didn't write it; you just wrote it with a horizontal line through its center. If you don't mean it, don't write it. That simple.

#### Regarding your suspension

We usually prefer not to discuss details of a suspension in public, so I won't reveal any details that aren't already common knowledge.

- This isn't the first time a message of yours was flag-deleted. In fact, this isn't the first time you asked here on meta why you were suspended.
- This isn't the first time you were suspended *that day*. One of your previous messages got flag-deleted for being pure noise, and your reaction to that 30-minute timeout was calling the moderators Nazis.
- You've been asked multiple times to post less nonsense in chat. You've ignored it every time.

Comment: ...

I just realized what I did.

I don't make my best decisions at (my best guess) 3-4 AM.

This post was made when I woke up, still not really myself.

I would have never posted something like that in chat if I had thought about it.

About the euphemism: Saying "crazy 1940s Germans" was meant to signify "crazy people, who were Germans, in the 1940s", it was in no way intended to offend people from Germany (unless they were crazy).

I should spend less time on reddit.

Comment: that last comment was meant to be split into lines. no idea how to do that in a comment

Answer (score 9):

You received a 7-day suspension because one of the mods saw your behavior and thought it was rude/inappropriate for respectful discourse. I say *one of the mods*, because us regular users don't know which one it was, and that is definitely a **good thing.**

IIRC, being suspended multiple times automatically increases the length of the suspension, which is why it was for 7 days.

The primary directive for good behavior for *all* of stack-exchange, including chat is [Be Nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). To quote some relevant sections...

> 1. *Rudeness and belittling language are not okay*. Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.
>
> ...
>
> 3. Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
>    - Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on ***race*, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc.** will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; **when in doubt, just don't.**)

Calling someone a Nazi is certainly something I wouldn't do when talking with someone in the real world. And calling someone "Crazy Germans" is definitely *"Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race*". Especially when you consider that quite a few of the PPCG mods are *actually from Germany*.

Even if you hadn't made a reference to Nazis, I would still consider calling the mods "mean people" for doing exactly what they're supposed to do rude.

There are *many* times I have seen a mod enforce a rule that I disagree with, or take a certain action I disagree with. I've even told that to mods to their faces before. However, I still greatly respect them for all their hard-work and maturity, and I appreciate that they're around to enforce *all* of the rules.

You need to realize that mods aren't arbitrarily making decisions in the moment based on their feelings, or guesses. They are enforcing *network-wide rules* that many people have spent time refining and clarifying. Whether or not you agree with these rules (or even if the mods agree with these rules) is irrelevant. If you use this site, you agree to abide by it's rules, and sometimes you'll have to pay the price for breaking them.

In the meantime, don't worry about it too much. We all make mistakes. In seven days, the suspension will be lifted and you can continue using chat like everyone else. After that, I would recommend being more careful about your choice of words.

---

As a side note, if there were no moderators around when you posted that message, you would probably still have received a suspension because I would have flagged your message if I was around to see it, and I can almost guarantee it would have been validated.

Comment: Two points I'd like to clarify: 1) suspensions don't *automatically* increase in length though that's the typical choice, and 2) I'm fairly sure I was the first mod to see that message, and I saw it about six hours later because I read the transcript.

Comment: For the record, the suspension was due to a validated chat flag - I was there to see the flag.

Comment: @mego I'm pretty sure it was a mod because validated chat flags are always 30 minutes

Comment: Uh, suspension time never increases *automatically*. (Kick times do.) wat *was* suspended for 30 minutes due to the chat flag, but was manually re-suspended for a week after discussion.